# Make a <td> as wide as possible

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a CMS-type system and will be listing content in tables. The problem is that because of how tables work by default, the right hand info (date created, views, etc.) takes up more space than is needed and looks well... silly. So I'm wondering if anyone knows of a way to force the title `<td>` to use up as much space as possible and therefore pushing the right hand content to the edge.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the width to 100%

```
<td width="100%">
```

it's a bit hacky but it works

Edit: to prevent other columns from squishing I use this on the OTHER columns:

```
<td class="no-wrap">
```

and stylesheet

```
<style>
.no-wrap 
{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `width` is old-fashioned and deprecated. Use CSS instead.

Comment: The only issue with this is that it squishes the text too much like so. http://cl.ly/image/2s0V171F1p2E

Comment: You sir, deserve a beer. :)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS might be like the following:

```
.tblX { width: 100%; min-width:480px; max-width:960px}    
.col1 { width: 10%; min-width:48px; max-width:96px}
.col2 { width: 70%; min-width:336px; max-width:672px}
.col3 { width: 20%; min-width:96px; min-width:192px}
```

And your HTML is like:

```
<table class="tblX">
    <tr>
        <td class="col1">some text</td>
        <td class="col2">some text</td>
        <td class="col3">some text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

You may change the proportions of the table's colum widths. Here comes the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PVfAW/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use percentages and create a css rule for a 'maximum' with on those outer td's.  see here for a CSS3 examples of word-wrapping, word-breaking. http://www.css3.com/css-word-wrap/